# Query on get_clock()->now()

Tags: ros, ros2, rostime, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to update the msg header stamp using the below method.

```
custom_msg.header.stamp = get_clock()->now();
```

Seems like this updates both `sec` and `nanosec` field in the `stamp`.

In the subscriber node, I need to use this timestamp to calculate the time difference. I have pasted the sample output below.

```
   header:
      stamp:
        sec: 1593787132
        nanosec: 472017003
      frame_id: custom_node
    ---
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 1593787132
        nanosec: 672051846
      frame_id: custom_node
    ---
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 1593787132
        nanosec: 872009918
      frame_id: custom_node
    ---
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 1593787133
        nanosec: 71999048
      frame_id: custom_node
    ---
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 1593787133
        nanosec: 271995190
      frame_id: custom_node
    ---
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 1593787133
        nanosec: 471998850
      frame_id: custom_node
    ---
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 1593787133
        nanosec: 671974068
      frame_id: custom_node
    ---
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 1593787133
        nanosec: 871955846
      frame_id: custom_node
    ---
```

Looks like I can not use the time in `sec` as it not changing in every cycle.
And in `nanosec` the time value decreases in some of the cycles resulting in negative difference.

Could anybody please explain how the `nanosec` is being updated. My understanding is that the value has to increase in each cycle.

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356352/query-on-get_clock()-%3Enow()/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2020-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Could anybody please explain how the nanosec is being updated. My understanding is that the value has to increase in each cycle.

The current time is the seconds + nanoseconds. Notice that when `nanosec` decreased it's because `sec` increased by 1.

To calculate the difference between two times you'll need to get the difference between the sum of those two. Thankfully there's already `rclcpp::Time` and `rclcpp::Duration` classes to handle that. Create two instances of [rclcpp::Time](http://docs.ros2.org/dashing/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Time.html) for the start time and end time, then subtract the two to get an [rclcpp::Duration](http://docs.ros2.org/dashing/api/rclcpp/classrclcpp_1_1Duration.html) containing the difference.

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2020-07-10**:
Thanks for the clear explanation. I was thinking both are not related to each other.